# Add a CSS class to an option in a WTForms SelectField

Tags: python, css, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

Can anyone please tell me how to assign css class to **choices** values.
I would like to change the background of each choices with small image, so how can I do it with wtforms and css?

```
class RegisterForm(Form):
    username = TextField('username', [validators.Length(min=3, max=50), validators.Required()])
    img_url = SelectField('avatar', 
            choices=[('static/images/avatars/1.jpg', '1'), 
                ('static/images/avatars/2.jpg', '2'),
                ('static/images/avatars/3.jpg', '3'), 
                ('static/images/avatars/4.jpg', '4'),
                ('static/images/avatars/5.jpg', '5'), 
                ('static/images/avatars/6.jpg', '6'),
                ('static/images/avatars/7.jpg', '7'), 
                ('static/images/avatars/8.jpg', '8'),
                ('static/images/avatars/9.jpg', '9'), 
                ('static/images/avatars/10.jpg','10')])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look deep in the bowels of `WTForms` you'll find a widget class called `SelectField`

this is the method called build the html string:

```
@classmethod
def render_option(cls, value, label, selected, **kwargs):
    options = dict(kwargs, value=value)
    if selected:
        options['selected'] = True
    return HTMLString('<option %s>%s</option>' % (html_params(**options), escape(text_type(label))))
```

this is `__call__` method that invokes the `render_options` function defined above.

```
def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('id', field.id)
    if self.multiple:
        kwargs['multiple'] = True
    html = ['<select %s>' % html_params(name=field.name, **kwargs)]
    for val, label, selected in field.iter_choices():
        html.append(self.render_option(val, label, selected))
    html.append('</select>')
    return HTMLString(''.join(html))
```

You are not going to be able to add the `class` attribute by simply instantiating a `SelectField`. When you do this it creates the `Option` instances implicitly. At render time the `render_options` methods of these implicit instances are only invoked with `val`, `selected`, and `label` arguments.

You can access the implicit `Option` instances after the fact. This is not without issue. If you look at @Johnston's example:

```
>>> i = 44
>>> form = F()
>>> for subchoice in form.a:
...     print subchoice(**{'data-id': i})
...     i += 1
```

He is doing exactly this. But you have to provide the attributes to the class at render time. The invocation `subchoice(**{'data-id': i})` actually spits out the expected `HTML`. This poses quite the problem if you are integrating `WTForms` with a template engine. Because the something like `jinja` is calling these render functions for you.

If you want this type of behavior I would recommend writing your own implementation of `SelectField` that allows you to pass attributes into the implicit `Option` instances. This way the template engine can just go about the business of invoking `render` and you can keep your definitions of the form consolidated in your `forms.py` file(s)

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to let you know that this is possible without monkey patching or rewriting wtforms. The library code does support it although not very straightforwardly. I found this out because I had the same issue as you and I attempted to write a fix for WTForms and submitted a PR myself and found out afterwards that you can just do this (I've spent days trying to figure this out):

```
>>> from wtforms import SelectField, Form
>>> class F(Form):
...    a = SelectField(choices=[('a', 'Apple'), ('b', 'Banana')])
... 
>>> i = 44
>>> form = F()
>>> for subchoice in form.a:
...     print subchoice(**{'data-id': i})
...     i += 1
... 
<option data-id="44" value="a">Apple</option>
<option data-id="45" value="b">Banana</option>
```

See the convo here:
https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/pull/81