# Load additional select field and data entries on flask admin edit and create form

Tags: python, flask-admin

I have a model Parent with a *Category* attribute and a model Unrelated with many entries.

In Flask-admin i need to extend or replace the edit/create functionality in such a way that i can  have an additional field on the form which has a dropdown with all the entries from an Unrelated model.

My plan is on the front, with JS, to check the value of *category* selected, and if it matches some string i'll show the user the Unrelated model field with the title *result*, otherwise it shows the normal *result* field. Then on the form submission i check which of the 2 result fields to use.

I am trying to use the form_extra_fields attribute, but im not sure how to load the values from the DB in this field.

```
Class MyView(ModelView):
  form_extra_fields = {
        #how to properly load all entries from the database at this point?
  }
```

I also tried modifying the scaffolding, but the result field (which in the model is a simple string), shows no dropdown

```
    def scaffold_form(self):
    form = super(MyView, self).scaffold_form()
    
    with Session() as session:
        all_objects = session.query(Unrelated).filter().all()
        choices = ((m.status, m.status) for m in all_objects)
        
        form.result.choices = choices

        return form
```

Answer (score 1):

To add an additional field:

```
form_extra_fields = {
    'Unrelated': SelectField('Unrelated label', widget=Select2Widget(), choices=[('', '')]),
}
```

Note that you have to provide choices, even if empty, otherwise the field will throw and error

```
   def render(self, template, **kwargs):
    '''
      This method is called just before the form is render. Here you can add extra choices and custom JS if you want.
      '''

    #Checks that the form is not being called on the list or delete page
    if not is_form_submitted() and (template == 'admin/model/edit.html' or template == 'admin/model/create.html'):

        #add custom JS
        self.extra_js = [url_for('static', filename='optionalCodeForFrontEndValidatiion.js')]

        form = kwargs['form']

        #Get the field entries from the database. filter and order by are optional.
        all_entries = (request.db_session.query(Unrelated).filter().order_by().all())
        
        #transform them to an iterable for the field
        unrelated_field_choices = ((m.name, m.name) for m in all_entries)
        
        #assign them to the field
        form.unrelated.choices = unrelated_field_choices
         
    #continue the render workflow
    return super().render(template, **kwargs)


def validate_form(self, form):
    """Custom validation code called on form submit. 
    """
    
    #check that we are not being called on load or on delete
    if is_form_submitted() and 'unrelated' in form.data:

        #here we can play with the submited form data and transform what is inside, then pass
        #it to the usual validation flow
        form = self.validate_your_data_conditions(form)

    return super().validate_form(form)
```

Additionally, i managed to pass custom css attributes to the frontend by using the information from this answer:

[Create selectfield options with custom attributes in WTForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460857/create-selectfield-options-with-custom-attributes-in-wtforms)